# TortoiseGit... switch to local or remote branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

TortoiseGit lists my local branches like "add-spaceships" and also "remote/origin/add-spaceships" when I want to `switch`. If I already committed+pushed my local branch, is there any difference which I pick? Any general rule on which is right?

*(I'm a noob to Git, simple answers preferred!)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remote/origin/add-spaceships` is a remote branch, an indication (and reference) of the state of your remote repository's branch. If you just pushed the local branch to this remote, it should be at the same commit of your local `add-spaceships` branch's tip.

Your development must happen on local branches, so just switch to `add-spaceships`.

Comment: Thanks. When I selected a remote/... branch, it wanted me to create a new local branch, so this makes sense with your answer.